# rar and zip password encoding scheme

Tags: passwords, encoding, zip

What encoding scheme is used in last versions of ZIP archives(6.3.2+) and RAR archives(3.90+), including RAR5? UTF-8/16, ASCII or something else?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this does not really seem to be about information __security__. Question about password algorithms would be, but which character encoding is used is not really a security aspect.

Comment: And where should i post this question? The same reaction was on crypto stack exchange.

Comment: Sure, this has nothing to do with cryptography either. Given that you "just" want to know it and don't show a specific problem you want to solve with this knowledge there might be no appropriate stackexchange site at all (i.e. it is off-topic at stackoverflow.com too). You might need to dig into the relevant file format specifications yourself to find out.